# Disable Alt hotkey / Firefox Safe Mode

Tags: firefox, hotkeys

I like to use global hotkeys to launch my favorite apps:

- Control+Alt+G Google Chrome
- Control+Alt+T Terminal
- Control+Alt+E Emacs

Using AutoHotKey, Quicksilver, or Ubuntu settings.

I'd like to be able to launch Firefox with Control+Alt+F, but Firefox has a built-in hotkey that plays foul with this setup. Turns out Firefox opens in Safe Mode when Alt is held down during launch. How can I disable this setting, so that I can launch a normal Firefox process with my preferred hotkey, Control+Alt+F?

Comment: From @saygon: With the Customizable Shortcuts plugin for Firefox you can change default hotkey values and set that to what you like.  https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

With the [Customizable Shortcuts](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) plugin for Firefox you can try change default hotkeys value and set that what you like.

Comment: External links can disappear or be unavailable, in which case your answer would have no value.  The purpose of Super User is to compile a knowledge base, so link-only answers are discouraged for this reason.  The name of the plug-in can be added to the answer, which would at least allow a manual search if the link goes bad.  However, plug-ins come and go, and often don't work with later versions of Firefox.  With a potentially limited life, they don't make good answers.  I'll move the information to a comment so it isn't lost if your answer gets deleted.

Comment: Customizable Shortcuts does not allow customization of this particular hotkey.

Comment: Hm... Ok, i found another one plugin you can try called [KeyConfig](http://mozilla.dorando.at/) is unoficial plugin for Firefox. Maybe this one have premmision for edit this particular hotkey.

Comment: People, please try out your solutions before blindly posting them!